# Chrome extension that runs in the background on window open event?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I make a Chrome extensions that is not a popup or a button?

1. I wanna have a script running whenever the window is opened and iterate thru all its tabs performing actions on each tab.
2. I also need (is this possible?) want to add to the same extension buttons (+keyboard shortcuts?) that when clicked, perform actions on all tabs.
3. Then I need control on these buttons visibility, and make them visible only in certain conditions (e.g. show only when page is loading, hide when not-loading).

Where do I put my script and how do I refer to it in my *.json manifest?

Any info/links will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? You are putting multiple questions in one and asking mostly about basic stuff. Pretty strange behavior for an 'established user'. Start with reading about background pages in chrome extensions developer docs.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Exactely. I started typing a comment with the same intent. As usual, I tried to help, so I said something like "What efforts have you shown so far? X can be found in Y, Z in A and Foo in Bar, ..".. Then I ran out of space, and turned it in a full-fledged answer. Now I've typed it, I *can* imagine that inexperienced users would never get at that point, because it requires some background knowledge about Chrome extensions.

Comment: @RobW Anyway, Shimmy was lucky to get such a detailed answer and I hope he appreciates that, good job!

Comment: @KonradDzwinel & Rob, unfortunately, I missed out the "background" part in the documentation, I was looking for it in the manifest, didn't see it's there, I can try to delete this question if this will make you happy. Or perhaps downvoting makes you happier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers to 0 and 1 can directly be found in the documentation, specifically [background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), [`chrome.windows` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html) and [`chrome.tabs` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html).

To bind global events, use the [`chrome.experimental.keybinding`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.keybinding.html) API. Because this API is experimental, you have to enable it first at `chrome://flags`. Also, the extension cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web store.
If you want to add an "extension button" which performs some action on click, define a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) and bind an event listener to [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked).
To select all tabs, use [`chrome.tabs.query({}, callback)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) method (`{}` means no filter, so all tabs are selected).

Browser action buttons are always visible. If you want to create a button which is not always visible, use a [page action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html) instead. The `chrome.tabs` module includes several [events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#global-events) which can be used to find out whether your conditions are met.

As for putting up the script and the manifest file, read the documentation on [Manifest files](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) and explore some [examples](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html).

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I was looking for the background thingy in the wrong area... Thanks for illuminating it for me.